# Laravel Blade components and slots: slot content not displayed beside each other

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working with blade components and I have a component with two slots. I want to pass an image to the first slot and text to the second. They should be displayed beside each other, but they are displayed in separate lines.

code snippet of slots:

```
<h1>
    {{ $icon }} {{ $title }}
</h1>
```

code snippet of filling the slots:

```
@component('components.pageheader')
       @slot('icon')
            <img src="{{ asset('img/an_image.png') }}" width="28px" height="28px">
       @endslot
       @slot('title')
            myTitle
       @endslot
@endcomponent
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `style="display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;"` on the `<img>` tag

Comment: Thank you! It works.I put the <img> tag in a <div style="display:inline-block margin-right:10px>" If you like to, post it as answer and I will accept it!

Comment: Have posted as answer as suggested for benefit of subsequent visitors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the display:inline-block on wrapper div for img like below

```
@component('components.pageheader')
       @slot('icon')
            <div style="display:inline-block; margin-right:10px">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/an_image.png') }}" width="28px" height="28px">
            </div>
       @endslot
       @slot('title')
            myTitle
       @endslot
@endcomponent
```